# link inside react markdown body is not opening in new tab

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hyperlink, markdown

I am working on a react app where I am rendering a content inside react markdown format where it also contains link.

```
<div>
   <ReactMarkdown>{this.state.post.body}</ReactMarkdown>
</div>
```

In this body,there is a link in markdown format but while rendering when I click on it,it takes my react page url and embed that link at the last and open which obviosuly doesnt work.

In markdown the link text is in this format:

```
[bit.ly/3sZbeYG](bit.ly/3sZbeYG)
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: https://github.com/remarkjs/react-markdown/issues/65

Answer (score 0):

The Easy way out is making

The Path absolute

> `[link](https://google.com)`